# Does Big Query adapts to the data?

Tags: google-bigquery

We use BigQuery as an analytical engine of our system that prepares the data for reports. 
According to our processes any part of the data may be changed, also historical values for 2013-2015, so we erase and reload all the tables in BigQuery every morning.

We would like to understand whether our method hurts performance or increases data processing costs. As it may be, that BQ "*adapts*" to the table content over the time and subsequent queries become more performant. I'm not talking about cache, but about some data reorganization, like partitioning, that BQ may discover while processing queries.

For example, the majority of the queries are related to a specific year, or a value type, so BQ may want to partition the data across those fields, once recognizes common query patterns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, BigQuery *does* refactor your tables based on how they are being queried in order to improve performance. If you rewrite your tables every day, you'll miss out on some of that performance advantage, but since you're loading the data all at once, the tables should be pretty performant.

The mechanism you're using doesn't increase data processing costs. If you are cost-sensitive, and querying for a specific year, you might want to consider breaking your table up into multiple tables. You can then query across those tables with the TABLE_DATE_RANGE or TABLE_QUERY functions.

Comment: I confirm this behaviour of Google BQ. Query execution plan does change over time even when the data was not changed. Unfortunately, in our case wildcards tables are not an option, as we use BI tool which generates SQL code itself.

Answer (score 1):

From first glance, it might look not related - but check [Table Decorators][1]
And specifically comments in [Syntax Section][2]
You might notice heavy mentioning of 7days in them

So, below my few cents on your question - simplified view:
When you load data to GBQ - it stays as is for 7 days, after which your data being storage- and access-wise optimized.
This is what you are losing because of your daily re-load.
How big that lost? Based on Jordan's answer - not much because you do full load, thus fragmentation is potentially minimal if at all

As of partitioning, I hope you are not storing all 2013-2016 data in one big table.
If your usage/query-pattern is based on year – you better have tables partitioned by year or month or even day (depends on your query pattern)
This will greatly improve you performance and cost-efficiency

Important – as of now, it is up to you to take care of partitioning strategy for your data and there is no much (if at all) built-in functionality to support building partitions. Though, there is some support for consuming partitioned data – for example - [Table wildcard functions][3]

I hope Google Team will come up with better support for partitioning as this becomes more and more demanded for real-life use cases

[1]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#tablewildcardfunctions  I hope Google Team will come up with better support for partitioning
[2]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators#snapshot-syntax
[3]: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#tablewildcardfunctions